# How to show Block 2 Below Block 1 oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have form with 2 Blocks and both Blocks on different canvas. I have save button on Block 1. I want when save button press then Block 2 canvas show below the Block 1 Form and Block 1 remains on the form.

I used

```
SET_VIEW_PROPERTY('CANVAS_NAME2', VISIBLE, PROPERTY_TRUE);
Go_block('block_name2');
```

But this code open Block 2 on another form. I need block 2 show below the block 1

I am using oracle forms 11g

How to achieve this target?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block 1 should be placed on the content canvas, while Block 2 should be on the **stacked** canvas so that you could position it anywhere you want (i.e. below block 1).